# How to copy segment from the image?

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I have Emgu image :

```
Image<Bgr,byte> image = new Image<Bgr,byte>("image.jpg");
```

Here is how the file(image.jpg) looks like:

[image]

All pixels that inside red-yellow triangle I want to copy to the new image called:

```
Image<Bgr,byte> copiedSegment;
```

Any idea how to implement it if I have coordinates all coordinates of the triangle contour.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the opencv c++ api you can just use the matrix copy function with a mask composed of your triangular components.

```
Mat image = imread("image.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
vector<Point> triangleRoi;
Mat mask;

//draw your trianlge on the mask
cv::fillConvexPoly(mask, triangleRoi, 255);

Mat copiedSegment;
image.copyTo(copiedSegment,mask);
```

You should beable to write some similar code in emgu based on this.

Comment: Element,thanks for answer.
Any Idea how can I make transparent pixels that not inside the polygon?

Comment: To make use of transparency, I would suggest you look into the 4th channel in OpenCV documentation. Initialize your picture as a `CV_8UC4` and create a `cv::Mat` with zeros for the 4th channel and then merge the extracted 3-channel image with this "blank" channel.

Comment: scap, what is appropriate type of Mat in EMGU? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
// no we apply filter to get rid of Equalization Noise.
ImageBilateral = new Image<Gray, Byte>(grayImg.Size);
CvInvoke.BilateralFilter(grayImg, ImageBilateral, 0, 20.0, 2.0);
//ImageBilateral.Save(String.Format("C:\\Temp\\BilateralFilter{0}.jpg", counter));

retImage = AlignFace(ImageBilateral);

Point faceCenter = new Point(ImageBilateral.Width / 2, (int)Math.Round(ImageBilateral.Height * FACE_ELLIPSE_CY));
Size size = new Size((int)Math.Round(ImageBilateral.Width * FACE_ELLIPSE_W), (int)Math.Round(ImageBilateral.Width * FACE_ELLIPSE_H));

// Filter out the corners of the face, since we mainly just care about the middle parts.
// Draw a filled ellipse in the middle of the face-sized image.
Image<Gray, Byte> mask = new Image<Gray, Byte>(ImageBilateral.Size);

// draw Ellipse on Mask
CvInvoke.Ellipse(mask, faceCenter, size, 0, 0, 360, new MCvScalar(255, 255, 255), -1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LineType.AntiAlias, 0);
mask.Save(String.Format("C:\\Temp\\mask{0}.bmp", counter));

Image<Gray, Byte> temp1 = ImageBilateral.Copy(mask);
ImageBilateral.Save(String.Format("C:\\Temp\\ImageBilateral.CopyTo(mask){0}.bmp", counter));
temp1.Save(String.Format("C:\\Temp\\temp1{0}.bmp", counter));
```